# Want to pass contract to the Application layer in CLEAN architecture

Tags: c#, clean-architecture

As per CLEAN architecture design rule, API/Web/Presentation cannot have reference of Domain and Application layer does not have reference of Contracts.
So now, I have very lengthy contract/[request object] which we are accepting in one of the controller's action.
I want to pass this entire contract/[request object] to Application project. It is not possible to pass each attribute as function parameter:

```
 [HttpPost("process")]
    public IActionResult Process(Root entityInput)
    {
        //_processEntityService is in application project
        //I want to pass this Root object to Service project below instead of each param as I tried below

        var resullt = _processEntityService.ProcessEntity(
            entityInput.Companies.First().CompanyMainName.Name
            ,entityInput.Companies.First().CompanyType);
        return Ok(resullt);
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you can create a new project called contract, and then send your Root as RootInputDto, then simply send it to your service:

var resullt = _processEntityService.ProcessEntity(entityInput);

then try to map it in your application service.

Comment: I think you can manage it by simply sending an application model to your application service. And inside, make whatever necessary mapping. You can also create a separate presentation model and map it to the application in the controller before passing it down. Contracts might be defined in the application (by contracts I mean interfaces and models for the infrastructure)

Comment: That's where i have contradictory opinion, if I have to map my request with exactly same DTO? What's the point of not having contract reference with Application Layer.